# How to store incoming message into another folder in android?

Tags: android, sms, message

I want to block some incoming message which is come from particular number and then that message I want to store/move into another folder which is made by me.

Can is it possible? Can anyone suggest me the way using which I can fulfill my requirement..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code for the intent receiver that will read the SMS from intent received and show the message.

```
 public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";            
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";        
            }
            //---display the new SMS message---
            Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }                         
    }
}
```

And make sure to add this permission in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
</uses-permission>
```

Also, **`msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress()`** gives you the sender of the SMS and you can check if this number is in your block list or not. And then use **`msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();`** to store the content of the SMS in your database / file.

This [tutorial](http://www.apriorit.com/our-company/dev-blog/227-handle-sms-on-android) covers some of the aspects of your question.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes thats true but I want to redirect my incoming message into custom generated folder.. How can I do this?

Comment: How are you planning to store the data in the custom folder ?

Comment: Ok.. But at where I should write my path any idea?

Comment: I want to move my message directly into my custom folder if the number is in block list..

Comment: You need to create a database to store them I believe. Or if you directly want to store in a file, set the file path and append the contents with the body of the new message.

Comment: And once you move it to the custom folder, how do you plan to show it to the user ?

Comment: Or is the user never supposed to see it ?

Comment: Oh yes.. Actually that same thing I was thinking.. How can I display to the user? Do u have any idea for that?

Comment: My suggestion : store in SQLite database, with different columns for sender, time and body, etc. Then use a cursor to get all the data from the database. Populate the data on a ListView in your application.

Comment: :) Feel free to ask if you have further troubles regarding this. :)

Comment: Sure swayam.. Thanks. :) R u from which country?

Comment: Hey swayam for storing data in to database I need to create DB or according to your tutorial I can store data using contentResolver..??

Comment: A line from the documentation : A content provider is only required if you need to share data between multiple applications. For example, the contacts data is used by multiple applications and must be stored in a content provider. If you don't need to share data amongst multiple applications you can use a database directly via SQLiteDatabase.

Comment: So, going by this I dont think you would need to use a ContentResolver if your data will be kept only in your application. But however, if you have troubles thinking how to implement the SQLite db, then it's okay if you go for how they have done it in the tutorial. And, I am from India. :)